# XC upgrade plan

Tags: upgrades, xc

I've got a GT Avalanche 1.0 (it's 26" hardtail - so I think this question can be useful not only for me) and I like it. But now I can afford some upgrade.

My goals are:

- Reduce friction loss - I don't ride much on paved roads, so using slick tires is not an option for me.
- Increase braking power. My brakes are Avid Elixir 1 and I think I can get bigger rotors - will it be worthy?

Answer (score 1):

Stopping on disks can be improved by changing your pads to a softer type - You want to avoid sintered pads (ones with metal baked into them) and go for resin pads.  Downside is resin ones wear quicker, and are not as good in the wet.  Check the thickness and runout of your rotor too.   Don't bother upgrading your rear brake, the front does most of the work.

Another option might be to change the whole front brake system to a hydraulic instead of a cable based one.  They give more feedback as the fluid heats and expands.

Mud and gravel don't really have "rolling resistance" in the same way a hard surface like a road does.  Can you rephrase that part?

Try a different tread pattern on your tyres/tires, one with more and smaller knobs in the middle of the tread. This will be noticeable on road and packed soil.   If you want to paddle your way through mud then bigger chunkier lugs will help, but only on the shoulders, so will only bite if you've sunk in a bit, or when you're leaning.

Comment: Thanks! About rolling: I meant that it would be great if my wheels could spin more time and with less friction. I mentioned the terrain type just cause I don't really ride on paved roads much. I'll edit the question know

Comment: @k102 Consider a rebuild and clean of your axle bearings too.  New ball bearings and a clean out will help keep the cups/cones nice and smooth.  It'll freewheel for longer.